# Rails Model - Creating Using Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, I have the ability to create "lessons", and each lesson contains several "components". Right now, I'm trying to implement the ability to create a lesson from a template so it would duplicate/recreate the components from the template to the new lesson.

The data structure of my `component` is something like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  type: Section,
  content: "abc",
  section_id: null
},
{
  id: 124,
  type: Question,
  content: "abc?",
  section_id: 123
},
{
  id: 125,
  type: Section,
  content: "defg",
  section_id: null
},
{
  id: 126,
  type: Outcome,
  content: "defg?",
  section_id: 125
},
```

Desired outcome:

```
{
  id: 993,
  type: Section,
  content: "abc",
  section_id: null
},
{
  id: 994,
  type: Question,
  content: "abc?",
  section_id: 993
},
{
  id: 995,
  type: Section,
  content: "defg",
  section_id: null
},
{
  id: 996,
  type: Outcome,
  content: "defg?",
  section_id: 995
},
```

You can see that there's an association between the `Question`/`Outcome` and the `Section` through `section_id`.

In my lesson model, I'm looping through the components of a template and taking their attributes for the newly created lesson components.

```
class Lesson

  attr_accessor :lesson_template_id

  # == Callbacks ==============================
  after_create :create_template_components, if: :lesson_template_id_present?

  def lesson_template
    if @lesson_template_id != ''
      LessonTemplate.find(@lesson_template_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end


private

  def lesson_template_id_present?
    !!@lesson_template_id
  end


  def create_template_components
    if lesson_template
      lesson_template.components.each do |c|
        self.components.create!({
          type: c.type,
          content: c.content,
          section_id: c.section_id
        })
      end
    end
  end
```

But the problem is that the `section_id` is incorrect because the newly create sections would have a new/different `id`. How can I revise my model to make sure the components are created properly?

Comment: You mean `section_id: c.section_id` is wrong always? Sorry I am not getting the problem. Could you tell me the more?

Comment: Yes, using `create_template_components`, the `section_id` will always be 123 (for example), even though the `section_id` will be new.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shallow copy of `Section` object, and then create it and attach it to the new components.

```
def create_template_components
  if lesson_template
    lesson_template.components.each do |c|
      newSection = if c.type == 'Question'
        c.section && c.section.dup
      else
        nil
      end
      newSection.save if newSection
      self.components.create!({
        type: c.type,
        content: c.content,
        section_id: newSection.try(:id)
      })
    end
  end
end
```

[`#dup`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup)

> Duped objects have **no id assigned** and are treated as **new** records. Note
>   that this is a “shallow” copy as it copies the object's attributes
>   only, not its associations. The extent of a “deep” copy is application
>   specific and is therefore left to the application to implement
>   according to its need. The dup method does not preserve the timestamps
>   (created|updated)_(at|on).

Comment: What if I have multiple sections (123 and 125), and separate components associated with those sections? For example, component 124 associated with section 123, and component 126 associated with section 125.

Comment: @jj008 Do you want always a new section to be created when copying from template components? If not, when you want a new one?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new section when I'm creating a new lesson using a template. So if I create a new lesson, I want to have component 994 associated with section 993, and component 996 associated with section 995 (for example)

Comment: Ok, then the code I gave, always create new section.. `newSection = c.section && c.section.dup.create`

Comment: for `c.section`, did you mean `c.type = 'Section'`? Also, I'm getting an error saying undefined method `create`

Comment: There's no error but the `section_id` of the component is still not using the `id` of the newly created section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179937/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-jj008).

Answer (score 1):

My idea is an outer loop that duplicates sections. The **new** section id is used when recreating other components (outcomes and questions) in an inner loop, which will keep the associations updated and correct.

```
lesson_template.sections.each do |old_section|
  # outer loop: recreate section
   new_section = self.sections.create!({
    content: old_section.content
  })
  old_section.components.each do |old_non_section_component|
    # inner loop: recreate all components belonging to section
    self.component.create!({
      type: old_non_section_component.type,
      content: old_non_section_component.content,
      # use id from newly-created section, keeping correct association
      section_id: new_section.id # <-- IMPORTANT
    })
  end
end
```

It's probably worth updating your question to mention that you are using self-referrential single table inheritance, or whatever this technique is called. It's not something I've seen very often.

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for, but the main question is, when I'm creating a new component, how can I use the correct and new section id (when I have different sections and different components associated to those sections?

Comment: Well, if the new component you are creating is a section, you don't have to worry about setting section id. If the new component is a question, this solution should use the new section id. That's why I've named the var `new_section` and we're using its id.
(Now, if there are more types of components than just those two, or if there are some "orphan" questions that don't belong to a section, then that would complicate things.)

Comment: Section is a type of component and there are multiple types of components. I'm trying to figure out how to "duplicate" the sections and components from a template with each component having the correct corresponding section_id, according to the template.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. Does this solution not work? What behavior do you see?

Comment: I have revised the data in my question, I'm trying to create/duplicate what's on the template but keep the "association" (through the section_id)

Comment: OK, I've updated the code in my answer to handle your new data

Comment: Calling lesson_template.sections results in undefined method. I don't have inheritance between section and non-sections, the section_id is just a value.

Comment: Well, `lesson_template.components.where(type: 'Sections')` should also do it. (I thought that `lesson_template.sections` would work if STI was set up correctly, but maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: Also, `old_section` or any section do not have components. They are all components. Like the data structure that I posted, how would that affect the inner loop?

Comment: OK, well, that also was just an attempt at a shorthand; `old_section.components` could also be written `Component.where(section_id: old_section.id)`